# Add row to word document after particular row c# Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am using C# Interop library for making changes in Word document.

My requirement is that I want to find a table cell with some 'specific value'.

After getting index of the cell, I want to add a row after the cell the 'specific value' was found

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using below code but it adds row to end of table. But i want to find index of some column using ‘specific string value’ and then add row after parent of that column row.                                               Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
oWordDoc.Tables[2].Rows.Add(ref oMissing);